# Excel VBA: Private Sub procedure too large

Tags: excel, vba

I do not know much about VBA. I wrote the following sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E12")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E12").Value = "=Left(B12, 3)"
End If
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E14")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E14").Value = "=Left(B14, 3)"
End If
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E15")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E15").Value = "=Left(B15, 3)"
End If
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E16")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E16").Value = "=Left(B16, 3)"
End If
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E17")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E17").Value = "=Left(B17, 3)"
End If
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E18")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E18").Value = "=Left(B18, 3)"
End If
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E19")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E19").Value = "=Left(B19, 3)"
End If
```

...........

It continues to E148, then F12-F148... to R148; obviously too large. I'm not sure how to break this up or condense it. It allows you to click a cell and it populates with the first 3 letters of another cell.

I've tried making other modules and macros and calling them to the sheet, but I have no idea what I'm doing anymore. I was all proud of myself for getting as far as this, but now I'm at a roadblock.

Excel Version 2312

Comment: When E becomes F, what does B switch to?

Comment: Did you miss out E13 or is that intentional?

Comment: stays in the B column

Comment: yes, e13 is skipped. a few more are skipped, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Long
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    'in the range of interest?
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E12:R148")) Is Nothing Then
        r = Target.Row
        If r <> 13 And r <> 25 And r <> 56 Then '(eg) skip excluded rows
            On Error GoTo haveError 'allow for recovery
            Application.EnableEvents = False 'don't re-trigger the event
            Target.Formula = "=LEFT(B" & r & ", 3)"
            Application.EnableEvents = True 're-enable events
        End If
    End If
    
    Exit Sub 'normal exit
    
haveError:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'make sure this is back on...

End Sub
```